# Riverpod 2.0: override with value does not exist anymore

Tags: riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I have a provider named gameControllerProvider extends with ChangeNotifier, I initialize it first throw UnimplementedError.

```
final gameControllerProvider =
ChangeNotifierProvider<GameController>((ref) => throw UnimplementedError());
```

In my GameBodyWidget I ovverridewith value my gameControlllerProvider

```
class GameBodyWidget extends ConsumerWidget {
  /// {@macro game_body_screen}
  const GameBodyWidget({Key? key, required this.gameLevel}) : super(key: key);

  final GameLevel gameLevel;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, WidgetRef ref) {
    return ProviderScope(
      overrides: [
        gameControllerProvider.overrideWithValue(
          GameController()..initializeController(gameLevel, ref),
        ),
      ],
      child: Stack(
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
```

As you can see, the reason why I override the controller provider because I need to initialize and pass the parameter of WidgetRef and the GameLevel instance.
Yeah I know I can use the .family method but the problem there is that when I need to call this provider I always pass the parameter

```
ref.watch(gameControllerProvider('exampleParameter'));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the changelog says, `overrideWithValue` is temporarily removed.
But to begin with, in the code you shared, you shouldn't be using it.

Instead do:

```dart
ProviderScope(
  overrides: [
    gameControllerProvider.overrideWithProvider(
      ChangeNotifierProvider((ref) {
        return GameController()..initializeController(gameLevel, ref),
      }),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Using overrideWithValue here is unsafe as a `ChangeNotifier` is a stateful object. If the widget somehow rebuilt, your ChangeNotifier would be recreated and your state would be lost.

Using `overrideWithProvider` does not have this issue, as the provider will cache the ChangeNotifier.

Comment: can you update your answer, because the new update of the riverpod by using this  overrideWithProvider is deprecated

Comment: What to do if I want to force the state to be changed when ProviderScope gets rebuilt?

Answer (score 0):

For now you can use `overrideWithProvider`.

> This change is temporary, and these methods will be reintroduced in a later version.